# How to write JSON data to table

Tags: python, api, request, cx-oracle

I have been trying hard to push my data to table but no luck. Getting me error like *Error :  ORA-00984: column not allowed here*

from API -> Fetching data -> converting to dataframe -> creating -> tuple -> loading -> oracle table

**My Code:**

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle

url = "https://api.apilayer.com/tax_data/canada_rate_list"
headers = {"apikey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
js_rd = json.loads(response.text)

df = pd.DataFrame(js_rd["data"])

tp = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]

try:

    conStr = "hr/hr@localhost:1521/orclpdb"

    con = cx_Oracle.Connection(conStr)
    cur = con.cursor()

    sqlCode = (
        'Insert into HR.STATE values (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,TO_DATE(:8,"YYYY-MM-DD"))'
    )

    cur.executemany(sqlCode, tp)

    con.commit()

except Exception as err:

    print("Error : ", err)

finally:

    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

**My table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE "HR"."state" 
   (    
    "state" VARCHAR2(25), 
    "country" VARCHAR2(25), 
    "type" VARCHAR2(25),
    "pst" NUMBER, 
    "hst" NUMBER, 
    "gst" NUMBER(*,5), 
    "combined_rate" NUMBER(*,5), 
    "start" date
   );
```

**Following my Json data which I pulled from API**

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "state":"AB",
         "country":"CA",
         "type":"GST",
         "pst":0,
         "hst":0,
         "gst":0.05,
         "combined_rate":0.05,
         "start":"2008-01-01"
      },
      {
         "state":"BC",
         "country":"CA",
         "type":"GST,PST",
         "pst":0.07,
         "hst":0,
         "gst":0.05,
         "combined_rate":0.12,
         "start":"2012-04-01"
      },
      {
         "state":"MB",
         "country":"CA",
         "type":"GST,PST",
         "pst":0.07,
         "hst":0,
         "gst":0.05,
         "combined_rate":0.12,
         "start":"2019-07-01"
      },
      {
         "state":"NB",
         "country":"CA",
         "type":"HST",
         "pst":0.1,
         "hst":0.15,
         "gst":0.05,
         "combined_rate":0.15,
         "start":"2016-07-01"
      },
      {
         "state":"NL",
         "country":"CA",
         "type":"HST",
         "pst":0.1,
         "hst":0.15,
         "gst":0.05,
         "combined_rate":0.15,
         "start":"2016-07-01"
      },
      {
         "state":"NS",
         "country":"CA",
         "type":"HST",
         "pst":0.1,
         "hst":0.15,
         "gst":0.05,
         "combined_rate":0.15,
         "start":"2008-01-01"
      },
      {
         "state":"NT",
         "country":"CA",
         "type":"GST",
         "pst":0,
         "hst":0,
         "gst":0.05,
         "combined_rate":0.05,
         "start":"2008-01-01"
      },
      {
         "state":"NU",
         "country":"CA",
         "type":"GST",
         "pst":0,
         "hst":0,
         "gst":0.05,
         "combined_rate":0.05,
         "start":"2008-01-01"
      },
      {
         "state":"ON",
         "country":"CA",
         "type":"HST",
         "pst":0.08,
         "hst":0.13,
         "gst":0.05,
         "combined_rate":0.13,
         "start":"2008-01-01"
      },
      {
         "state":"PE",
         "country":"CA",
         "type":"HST",
         "pst":0.1,
         "hst":0.15,
         "gst":0.05,
         "combined_rate":0.15,
         "start":"2016-10-01"
      },
      {
         "state":"QC",
         "country":"CA",
         "type":"GST,PST",
         "pst":0.09975,
         "hst":0,
         "gst":0.05,
         "combined_rate":0.14975,
         "start":"2013-01-01"
      },
      {
         "state":"SK",
         "country":"CA",
         "type":"GST,PST",
         "pst":0.06,
         "hst":0.11,
         "gst":0.05,
         "combined_rate":0.11,
         "start":"2017-03-23"
      },
      {
         "state":"YT",
         "country":"CA",
         "type":"GST",
         "pst":0,
         "hst":0,
         "gst":0.05,
         "combined_rate":0.05,
         "start":"2008-01-01"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Error :** ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: Your table name is `HR.state_details`, not `HR.STATE` (as per the `CREATE TABLE` statement you show). `state` is a column in that table. Fix the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @buran : It was a typo error . I have corrected it

Comment: Then try replacing double quotes in `"YYYY-MM-DD"` with single quotes

Comment: @buran : Thank you bro it got loaded

Comment: @buran : I have taken in this format and it worked : `"Insert into HR.DEMO values (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,TO_DATE(:8,'YYYY-MM-DD'))"`

Comment: yeah, double quotes for the string, in order to use single quotes inside it. By the way, conversion to DF is unnecessary - `[tuple(x.values()) for x in js_rd['data']]`, as well as you can just use `response.json()` to parse the json response

Comment: For general reference, see the python-oracledb examples https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/blob/main/samples/json_blob.py and https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/blob/main/samples/json_direct.py